# why is my code running in an infinite loop? Putting something from two different files into two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can someone tell me why this code is running infinitely? I tried everything to fix it but still can't figure it out. The first half of the code works. But the second half doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner in;
    in = new Scanner (new File ("ratings"));

    int[] [] ratings = new int [30] [20];
    int j = 0;

    while (in.hasNextLine()){
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            ratings [j] [i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        j++;
    }
    in.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < ratings[i].length; k++){
            System.out.print(ratings [i][k] + "");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    Scanner in1;
    in1 =  new Scanner(new File("books"));

    String[] books = new String [20];

    while (in1.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
            books [i] = in1.toString(); 
        }
    }
    in1.close();
}
```

Comment: Kind of hard to read your code. Please consider improving your indentation. Each nested block of code, each for loop, while loop, etc should be indented 4 spaces.

Comment: Your loop calling `in1.toString()` never consumes anything from `in1` and is thus an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, guys for your comments. I'm new to stack and i still haven't got the hang of indenting the way stack wants me to. The way I indent won't work with stack either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last loop, since the books are string, you probably have a typo and would change the in1.toString to in1.next() or in1.nextLine() depending on your file structure and format:

`books [i] = in1.toString();` == e.g => `books [i] = in1.nextLine();`

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm new to stack and I still haven't learned how to intend like how stack wants me to.

Comment: No problem. We all have to learn at some point. Keep learning and sharing! :)